# Symfony 2 open_basedir error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, symfony

i installed a fresh symfony 2.5.5 on my server and i can't make it working. I added umask(0000); but nothing happend. I dont have acces to php.ini or terminal so i can't change anything related to serv. How can i bypass that error does anyone know?Thnx in advance.

> ContextErrorException: Warning: is_dir() [function.is-dir]:
>   open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/php4/lib/php) is not
>   within the allowed path(s):
>   (/home/websoft:/usr/lib/php:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/tmp)
>   in
>   /home/websoft/public_html/symfony2/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Process/ExecutableFinder.php
>   line 59

here is a link with all the errors i get: [LINK](http://websoftit.ro/symfony2/web/app_dev.php)

Comment: Which version of php are you using?

Comment: i use php 5.3 so it's not cause of that, i just don't know what happends, and i cant turn off open_basedir cause i don't have acces